# Get Related Model From M2M Intermediate Model

Tags: django

In signals.py I am catching `@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Manager.employees.through)`.

This is getting the signal sent when a m2m relationship is created between a Manager and an Employee.

I am trying to get the Employee that this particular relationship is referencing.

I am guessing `sender` is the 'through' relationship object, but really I'm not sure.

If I `print(sender)` I get `<class 'users.models.Manager_employees'>`.

I have tried `referenced_employee = sender.employee_id`, but this gives me `<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ForeignKeyDeferredAttribute object at 0x03616310>`.

`print(sender['employee_id'])` gives me `'ModelBase' object is not subscriptable`.

`print(sender.employee_id)` gives me an error `'ModelBase' object is not subscriptable`.

I'm really just trying everything I can think of at this point.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like `sender`, the signal also pass other arguments.

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Manager.employees.through)
def my_signal_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
    # kwargs is a dictionary
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        print(key, value)
```

Take the following example:

```
an_employee = Employee.objects.create(name='Brenden')
my_manager.employees.add(an_employee)
```

You will have the following items in the dictionary:

`kwargs['instance']` is the instance of the model being **changed**. In the example above, it will be `my_manager`

`kwargs['model']` is the class being added. In this case `Employee` and

`kwargs['pk_set']` will be `{an_employee.id,}`, a set of the keys being added, so you could do something like

```
my_employee = kwargs['model'].objects.get(id=kwargs['pk_set'][0])
```